# Can't get Recycle Bin path using SHGetKnownFolderPath

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, recycle-bin

Can't get Recycle Bin path using `SHGetKnownFolderPath`. Hard coding `C:\\$Recycle.Bin` is an option which I want to avoid. Is there a way around this issue?

```
static std::string GetKnownWindowsFolder(REFKNOWNFOLDERID folderId, const char* errorMsg) {
    LPWSTR wszPath = NULL;
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(folderId, KF_FLAG_CREATE, NULL, &wszPath);
    FreeCoTaskMemory scopeBoundMemory(wszPath);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        throw std::runtime_error(errorMsg);
    }
    return sago::internal::win32_utf16_to_utf8(wszPath);
}
```

Thank You!

Get the folder path of Recycle Bin

Comment: How do you tested? What's the result you get?

Comment: @tttony It is using a webview2 and I am getting a runtime error... 'NE_RT_NATRTER' A neutralino application

Comment: The recycle bin is a virtual folder which unifies the contents of the possibly multiple recycle bin directories from every drive in your system. It doesn't have **a** path.

Comment: @JonathanPotter So hard coding it is the only way going forward?????? Any other way

Comment: going forward to where? What are you trying to do? sounds like an XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

The Recycle Bin is a virtual folder (like Control Panel and My Computer), it does not have a traditional path.

These virtual folders can be represented by an `ITEMIDLIST`. Call `SHGetKnownFolderIDList()` to retrieve it. See [Introduction to the Shell Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro) for more information about the Shell Namespace and ItemIDLists.

That being said, there is a hidden Recycle Bin folder on each local drive, and the virtual folder displays a merged view of all of them. You can [check if a folder is the Recycle Bin folder](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080918-00/?p=20843).